# Corsair VS650 PSU Failure

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, capacitor

I wanted to ask if the PSU that just exploded repairable by just replacing the capacitor

Because I'm short on money and can't really afford a new PSU right now

its Capacitor is 400V + 360uF

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPWOb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oKC4.jpg

I really hope I can get help as soon as possible because this is the PC of my younger brother and he's a pain in the ass right now because he thinks I blew it up

ThankYou

Comment: If I remember correctly, every PSU has a sign saying "there are no user replaceable component inside" - and for a very good reason. It is converting electricity from AC to DC and high voltage around. Do NOT attempt what you are thinking of doing unless you are a trained electrician (and even then, trained in that particular PSU manufacturer as each one may do their wiring differently). Get the cheapest PSU from the shop is your safest bet. Assuming you are running a big gaming rig, simple 300W cheap PSU will do the job. Do not risk both your and your brother's life.

Comment: I have a mediocre gaming pc 

with Intel i5 6400 processor with ASUS 1151 Board

plus a GIGABYTE GTX 960 

is the 650W overkill for it 
or should I just buy the same brand again

Comment: Something not too high end seems to be deemed suitable. I use this site https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator and put your parts in (and with the assumption of 24/7 gaming, and 2 HDD, and 4 x 4GB RAM) - and they recommend about 350W PSU - so give a bit extra at about 400-450W and you should be safe to run most of them. Just take note of the PSU as your GTX960 may need extra plugs - just ensure the PSU you buy will have those power plugs.

Comment: You can never have "overkill" when it comes to PSU power ratings.  It is always better to have more power than not for the sake of overclocking components or upgrading.  Your GTX 960 requires 120W at idle and 236W during full stress. A 650W PSU is just about right for this, depending on how many other components you are powering (optical drive, lights, extra fans, CPU cooler, etc.).  If you don't have a ton of extra components you may be able to get away with a 500W PSU for the purposes of saving money, but a 300W will definitely leave your system underpowered with that GTX 960.

Comment: I just have 1x HDD ( 1TB ) + 8GB RAM DDR4
3x 120MM Fans
Cheap Keyboard and a Gaming Mouse

Yes the GTX960 does require an extra plug 


and the site recommends 380 
so is 500W enough?

The basic failure was caused by a failure from the part of our electricity providers
Our house had 400Volts of electricity for more than 2 hours 
and it ruined almost every electrical appliance in our house that was on at that time 

So I wanted to ask what can I do to prevent such a thing in future 
Because right now I'm not even sure if my other parts are burnt as well or not ( the GPU, CPU )

Comment: 500W is generally enough to power up 380. In regards to the 400V of electricity... that is what a surge protector is for. It sits between the wall plug and the rest of your equipment. When it detects a power surge - it will sacrifice itself (blown a fuse or however they deal with it) and cut power completely - keeping your electronic equipment safe, and all you need is either a new fuse, or a new surge protector plug/powerboard.

Comment: Hello
I bought a 550W PSU and when I hooked it up
Nothing worked
If i short the PSU using the paperclip it works ( I connected a light 120 MM fan ) but when I connect it to the motherboard ( ASUS H110M-D ) nothing works, the processor's fan isn't moving, neither is GPU's

Please tell me what to do